# How to use a MBP with broken graphics chip as a server?

Tags: unix, ssh

I have a 2012 MBP and the graphic chips gave up and the repair costs are huge.

Is there a way to use it as a Unix server somehow? It is still a powerful machine and if I  could boot into a mode without using anything that needs graphics that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought on boot you could close the lid and the display would run on an external?

Comment: @DarthVader : forgot that and I do it all the time as well... Hope the oP has a spare display.

Comment: The display is fine, it is one or more of the graphics chips (GPU) that are no longer working.

Answer (score 1):

Build the drive with the software on a separate machine or remote log in to it and set it up that way.

I have 2 machines I remote log in to but not due to a graphics failure so I can't say if it will have an error on booting

Comment: The problem is in the booting, it won't boot because it can't drive the display. A unix server runs without a screen and you can reboot it. So I was wondering if there was a way to boot the MBP in that sort of "server mode" so I can login into it with SSH from another machine.

Comment: Perhaps someone will have a way to edit the system check / kernel to skip the graphics test...